# how to add a 3 seconds countdown before calling the function to start a game in javascript

Tags: javascript

If I press the enter key, the game will automatically start. Now, I want to add the 3 seconds countdown before the game starts. How to make that available?

```
if((keyPressed[13] == true) && !STATE_START){
  startGame();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use setTimeout to delay execution of a function.

```
function countdown(time){
    if (time>0){
        console.log(time);
        setTimeout(function(){countdown(time-1)},1000);
        }else{
            console.log("GO");// replace with any function
        };
}
countdown(3);
```

Comment: A "delay" and a "countdown" are not the same thing.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helped me.

Comment: @nnnnnn: countdown is nothing but delay with timing cue, since there're no information provided about UI, it's safe to assume that OP want to delay the function.

Comment: By definition a "countdown" involves counting backwards from some number to the event, like "3...2...1...go". Nobody counts down from 1. So, again, a "delay" is *not* a countdown. Maybe OP will be happy with a simple delay, or perhaps they can extrapolate from this how to implement a countdown, but a simple delay certainly isn't what they asked for.

Comment: @nnnnnn: I've updated my answer. I hope it's more useful.

Comment: Dolphin - Looks like your answer was accepted before the edit, so I guess it helped as it was. I admit my complaint was entirely around what "countdown" means. But your edit obviously does an actual countdown, so I've upvoted that. Ria could replace the `console.log()` with setting the content of an element on their page for the user to see, and then replace the `console.log("go")` with `startGame()`.